# Android WebView not rendering properly

Tags: java, android, android-webview

I'm trying to make an Android app with a webview with custom caching. I need to intercept the request but when I do the rendering of the page gets all weird. I'm using Google as an example.

```
@Override
    public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request){
        try{
            URL url = new URL(request.getUrl().toString());
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            String contentType = conn.getContentType();
            contentType = contentType.contains(";") ? contentType.split(";")[0] : contentType;

            return new WebResourceResponse(contentType, conn.getContentEncoding(), conn.getResponseCode(), conn.getResponseMessage(), null, conn.getInputStream());
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
            return returnNull();
        }
    }
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. There were two byte chars encoded with gzip that weren't playing nice. This works for me

```
 @Override
    public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(request.getUrl().toString());
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod(request.getMethod());

            conn.connect();

            String contentType = conn.getContentType();
            contentType = contentType.contains(";") ? contentType.split(";")[0] : contentType;
            String mimeType = conn.getContentEncoding();

            InputStream inputStream;

            if(conn.getContentEncoding().equalsIgnoreCase("gzip")){
                inputStream = new GZIPInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
                mimeType = "UTF-8";
            }else{
                inputStream = conn.getInputStream();
            }

            return new WebResourceResponse(contentType, mimeType, conn.getResponseCode(), conn.getResponseMessage(), null, inputStream);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            return returnNull();
        }
    }
```